# git fails with missing ident on git filter-branch

Tags: git

I am trying to clear my repository of the commits I made to add bower_components and node_modules directories into it, after I decided I am better not including them.  Following the git-hub instructions here, suitably modified I did

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter \
'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch bower_components node_modules' \ 
--prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

But I got this error

```
fatal: empty ident name (for <@localhost>) not allowed
```

All other answers to this problem involve using git config --global to add your name and e-mail address.  But I did this long ago, and has been working for years.  So that answer is not correct in this case.

I suspect its something to do with the fact that git filter-branch makes its own environment for something it is doing, but I don't know what or how to fix it.  I tried adding

```
 --env-filter 'export GIT_COMMITER_EMAIL=my@emailaddress'
```

before the --prune-empty flag but it didn't make any difference.

So how can I get rid of this error?

UPDATE:  I have found some commits in my repository with @localhost committer details, and I expect that has something to do with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I turns out that there was rubbish e-mail idents in the repository and that was the cause of the error message.  It was quite hard to get rid of because depite following the instructions here

https://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info/

I ended up still leaving the bad addresses because of stashes and old obscure branches meaning the bad addresses were not pruned away.  But I managed it eventually.

Then following the instructions I mentioned above it completed the process fine.  My repository size has dropped from 615M to 214M